# ASP.net Thread Safety Confusion

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I have a very long running process in an ASP.net application that we desperately need to dramatically shorten. The process in question is charging a large number of credit cards. Currently it performs at about 1 charge per second. We need this to be more like 10 per second.

So we decided that utilizing multiple simultaneous threads would be one way to go. So we basically take this large list of orders to process, divide the list into ten lists and then spawn a new thread to process each of the ten lists simultaneously.

An additional complication of this process is that we need to report progress on this process, and not only to the user session that initiated the process, but to any user, in any session in the application. So for example, if I log in and start this process, I will see a progress bar. If after I initiate the process, and it is still running, another user logs in elsewhere and goes to this same page, they will also see the progress bar.

I did some research and thought that I could use Application variables to store the relevant bits of information required to report progress. The client polls the server on a regular basis whenever on this page to see if there are any threads running, and if so, it returns various statistics on the progress of the process back to the client.

It would seem that this approach does not work. A simple counter of the number of currently running threads does not work as expected. It seems that the so-called thread safety of the Application object is safe in that no two threads will be able to access the same variable simultaneously, but not safe in that if two threads both attempt to increment a variable, one of them will be able to increment it, and the other will not, and rather than queue up and increment it in turn, the second thread just moves on. I'm sure this is my thread safety ignorance shining through.

Another issue is that using Debug.Print or Debug.WriteLine seem to be the same kind of "thread-safe" as the Application object. As each thread starts, we use Debug.WriteLine to output the name and start time of the thread, and as it completes, we do the same thing to write that it completed. We consistently see ten threads start and four threads end in the debug window.

I don't think we need to use Application.Lock() and Application.Unlock(), but I have tried it both with and without those calls before and after every write operation, but to no avail- the results are the same either way.

I have a ton of code, so I'm not sure exactly which parts to share, but here are some of the relevant parts:

This is how we create and start the threads:

```
For Each oBatch As List(Of Guid) In oOrderBatches
    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(Sub() ProcessPaymentBatch(oBatch, clubrunid, oToken.UserID))
    t.IsBackground = True
    t.Start()
Next
```

Here is the sub that is started by each thread:

```
Private Sub ProcessPaymentBatch(oBatch As List(Of Guid), clubrunid As String, UserID As Guid)

    ThreadsRunning(clubrunid) += 1

    Try
        Debug.Print("Thread Start")
        For Each oID As Guid In oBatch
            ‘Do a bunch of processing stuff…
        Next
    Finally
        ThreadsRunning(clubrunid) -= 1
        Debug.Print("Thread End")
    End Try

End Sub
```

Finally, this is an example of one of the application variables that the threads attempt to access, but seems to be failing.

```
Private Const _THREADSRUNNING As String = "ThreadsRunningThisRun_"
Public Property ThreadsRunning(clubid As String) As Integer
    Get
        Dim sToken As String = _THREADSRUNNING & clubid
        If Application(sToken) Is Nothing Then
            ThreadsRunning(clubid) = 0
        End If
        Return Application(sToken)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        Debug.Print(value)
        Dim sToken As String = _THREADSRUNNING & clubid
        Application.Lock()
        Application(sToken) = value
        Application.UnLock()
    End Set
End Property
```

The Debug output from this property looks something like this:

```
Thread Start
1
Thread Start
Thread Start
1
1
4
Thread End
5
3
Thread Start
6
3
1
-1
Thread End
-2
-3
```

I can't understand why there would be a different number of "Thread Start" and "Thread End" debug statements, and I don't understand how the thread count could get to negative numbers. This is why I am confused by the thread safety of the Application and Debug objects.

Your help in this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess you are changing data. So a smarter way might be to push the operation into the database.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was just being an idiot. The problem had nothing to do with the Application or Debug objects not being thread safe, the problem was in my methodology (as was expected really).

To clarify, the issue was that we were locking the global variables in the application object when writing, but not when reading. We then tried also locking when reading, but still had the same problem. What we failed to realize was that when incrementing a value, you are getting the current value, adding onto that, then setting the new value. The lock needed to bridge all three of those operations, so it goes like this:

- Lock
- Get
- Add
- Set
- Unlock

What we were doing previously was:

- Lock
- Get
- Unlock
- Add
- Lock
- Set
- Unlock

Which allowed for multiple threads to Get and then Set the same values as one another, which explains all of the oddities we were seeing in the debug window.